# DYNAMICS AX 2012 R2 TABLE LOOKUP

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Here's the scenario,

Disclaimer: I'm a total NEWBIE TO DYNAMICS AX, USING AX 2012 R2

I need to be able to create a table, lets call it TABLE A, that allows for one to have a lookup of all other tables I have in my AOT. Now in my TABLE A, I want to have two columns, one that selects the table and a second column, B that selects a table field from the table specified in column A.

After doing this, I expect to have a TABLE B that will now just be looking up column B (the one with the fields) from table A

Is this doable and if yes, could one of you kindly guide me on how to go about it soonest possible.

May be share an XPO even :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is doable, Dynamics AX out of the box does similar things already in several places. I suggest you take a look at the extended data types `RefTableId` for table fields that reference another table and `RefFieldId` for table fields that reference another table field. Use cross references to find out what tables use these extended data types and how these tables work. From there you should be able to build your own solution.